# Doesnt save userdefaults once the app closes

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, nsuserdefaults

I have created an app that is a uitableview that has 5 arrays of cell `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` that can edit when the cell is tapped. I have accomplish that when you tapped a cell it shows an alertview and a textfield. You can edit the cell in short. And i have save the edit when it goes to another view controller. But the problem is when i try to close the app and open it, It goes back to the default number of messages like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]. Any tips how can i save the edited cell but at the same time when the uitableview is opened it shows the array. Sorry for my english. Thanks btw i am new to programming sorry for this code

*Messages.Swift = tableview

```
class Messages: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var uitableView: UITableView!

    var tField: UITextField!
    var index: Int?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        //Get the array
        if let array = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"messages") as? Array<String> {
            self.app.helper.messages = array
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return app.helper.messages.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let messagesCell = app.helper.messages[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = messagesCell

        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let path = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        index = path?.row

        changeMessage()
    }

    func changeMessage() {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Message", message: "Enter new preset message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

        alert.addTextField(configurationHandler: configurationTextField)

        let doneAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Save", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler:{ (UIAlertAction) in

            let modelString = self.tField.text
            self.app.helper.messages[self.index!] = modelString!
            self.app.helper.saveToDefaults()
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        })

        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)

        alert.addAction(doneAction)
        alert.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func configurationTextField(textField: UITextField!){
        if (textField) != nil {
            tField = textField
            textField.text = app.helper.messages[index!]
        }
    }
}
```

*Helper.swift

```
class Helper {

var messages: [String] = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]

    func saveToDefaults() {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        defaults.set(messages, forKey: "messages")
        defaults.synchronize()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to load user default before setting the table view delegate. Because the table view is loading with the dataset you assigned in helper, not with the dataset from user default.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Get the array
    if let array = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"messages") as? Array<String> {
        self.app.helper.messages = array
    }

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}
```

Or you can reload the table view in view will appear after loading the dataset from user defaut

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    //Get the array
    if let array = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"messages") as? Array<String> {
        self.app.helper.messages = array
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: but first you need to confirm that the data is actually being loaded.  Have you checked that 'self.app.helper.messages' is being populated?

Comment: yes the app.helper.messages is being populated by the entered textfield.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    //Get the array
    if let array = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:"messages") as? Array<String> {
        self.app.helper.messages = array
    }
    //make this array global(declare it below var index: Int?)
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and

```
let messagesCell = array[indexPath.row]
```